# How to templating json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Let's say my json like this and i have 3 different data

```
[  
   {  
      "Pair":"",
      "Id":"8ca2df56-2523-4bc3-a648-61ec4debcaaf",
      "PubDate":"/Date(1463775846000)/",
      "Provider":null,
      "Market":""
   },
   {  
      "Pair":"",
      "Id":"74b2d7c7-bc2c-40ee-8245-7c698befa54d",
      "PubDate":"/Date(1463775247000)/",
      "Provider":null,
      "Market":""
   },
   {  
      "Pair":"",
      "Id":"0ee3cd96-1df8-49ba-b175-7a75d0840973",
      "PubDate":"/Date(1463773687000)/",
      "Provider":null,
      "Market":""
   }
]
```

What I already try

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'news.json', 
            data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { 
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                   $( ".content-news h3" ).append(  data[0].Title  );
                   **/** Stuck Here and it only call 1 data but i already use each function **/**
                });
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="news">

                        <div class="ano">
                            <div class="content-news">
                                <h3 id="jtitle"> **/** I Want to Show Id Here **/** </h3>
                                <h4 id="jprovider" class="author">**/** I Want To Show  PubDate **/**</h4>
                                <p id="jsummary">
**/** I Want to Show Provider Here **/**
                                </p>
                                <div class="img-head" id="img-container">
    <!--                            <img src="" alt="img" class="img-responsive">-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="social-control">
                                <div class="head-control">
                                    <p id="jdate" class="inline gray"></p>
                                    <a href="#"><p class="pull-right">show more</p></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="footer-control">
                                    <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-heart ion-spacing"></i>20</a></p>
                                    <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="ion-chatbox ion-spacing"></i>2 comments</a></p>
                                    <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-android-share-alt ion-spacing"></i>share</a></p> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>





                    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65zjvy5k/)

I managed to out only 1 result. Can you guys give a hint or tips show me how to templating jquery using json. Please be easy on me. Thanks

THIS IS THE RESULT WHAT I GET RIGHT NOW, Only 1 data display.. 
[image]

Comment: @robert please show me how to do this.

Comment: @robert, `dataType: 'json'` will take care of that..

Comment: @robert that doesn't generate html and is also not needed when dataType is set to `'json'`

Comment: @Fido there are numerous ways to generate the html. As strings...as jQuery objects....using template engines are several. To be honest you should easily find tutorials for this

Comment: @charlietfl i already try my hardest. i'm still cant find the way .

Comment: What are you stuck on? Accessing the properties?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ to display the json data from html .. Please check the HTML you will find out

Comment: @charlietfl i already tried doing like this but it only display 1 data
please check the jscript
$( ".content-news h3" ).append(  data[0].Title  );
                   **/** Stuck Here and it only call 1 data but i already use each function **/**

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz are you sure an array is returned?

Comment: @charlietfl like i say the result that i get right now it's only display 1 data from jason. I'm not sure if i'm doing right please correct me. thanks

Comment: @Mike the array not return idk where is the wrong.

Comment: @charlietfl check my jsfiddle. In the title section I want ID from json put at content news h3 tag * example

Comment: Exactly which portion on the html are you trying to template? The entire bit posted or just a piece of it, like the `<div class="content-news">` part? Hard to post a definitive answer when the question keeps changing.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ the <div class="content-news"> part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you json file have array of objects so first you need to loop for the objects one by one

also don't use `each` for serialized array cause it takes more time just use the normal `for` loop

answer is here jsfiddle.net/robert11094/65zjvy5k/3

or just use this html page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://subscriptions.fxstreet.com/json/news.aspx?c=A0DC975D13C44CE697EC&i=englishnewscharts',
            data: { get_param: 'value' },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var html=
                    '<div class="ano">'+
                    '    <div class="content-news">'+
                    '        <h3 id="jtitle"> '+data[i].Id+' </h3>'+
                    '        <h4 id="jprovider" class="author">'+data[i].PubDate+'</h4>'+
                    '        <p id="jsummary">'+
                    data[i].Provider+
                    '        </p>'+
                    '        <div class="img-head" id="img-container">'+
                    '            <!-- <img src="" alt="img" class="img-responsive">-->'+
                    '        </div>'+
                    '    </div>'+
                    '    <div class="social-control">'+
                    '        <div class="head-control">'+
                    '        <p id="jdate" class="inline gray"></p>'+
                    '        <a href="#"><p class="pull-right">show more</p></a>'+
                    '    </div>'+
                    '    <div class="clear"></div>'+
                    '        <div class="footer-control">'+
                    '            <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-heart ion-spacing"></i>20</a></p>'+
                    '            <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="ion-chatbox ion-spacing"></i>2 comments</a></p>'+
                    '            <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-android-share-alt ion-spacing"></i>share</a></p>'+
                    '        </div>'+
                    '    </div>'+
                    '</div>';
                    $('.news').append(html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="news">
    <div class="ano">
        <div class="content-news">
            <h3 id="jtitle">Hello World</h3>
            <h4 id="jprovider" class="author">David</h4>
            <p id="jsummary">
                This is content
            </p>
            <div class="img-head" id="img-container">
                <!--                            <img src="" alt="img" class="img-responsive">-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-control">
            <div class="head-control">
                <p id="jdate" class="inline gray"></p>
                <a href="#"><p class="pull-right">show more</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="footer-control">
                <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-ios-heart ion-spacing"></i>20</a></p>
                <p><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="ion-chatbox ion-spacing"></i>2 comments</a></p>
                <p><a href="#"><i class="ion-android-share-alt ion-spacing"></i>share</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is virtually useless without an explanation and it does nothing to generate html

Comment: i'm still working on it , need to save from time to time

Comment: Then don't post partial useless answers

Comment: if you like that way then use it , don't force others to use it too

Comment: Hi @robert thanks for help, i try your code and it shows unexpected identifier

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz try it now

Comment: @charlietfl what do you think of the answer now ?

Comment: Certainly more complete...not removing downvote though...what you first posted was pure garbage. write a concise solution...then post it

Comment: @charlietfl if you saw bad answer you should downvote it , then if the answer is edited to better version you have to un downvote it by the rules of the SO and upvote it if you saw it worth it

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/robert11094/65zjvy5k/3/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://subscriptions.fxstreet.com/json/news.aspx?c=A0DC975D13C44CE697EC&i=englishnewscharts&get_param=value'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: it won't work from `jsfiddle.net` because the site using `https` while the link you gave me use `http` so it's not secure to use on this site

Comment: see the edited answer copy the code in html page in your pc and run it

Comment: Yes its work thanks OMG robert you are the best.. tbh i'm not good with jquery and js .. Can give me the reference how to be good at this stuff

Comment: Sorry if i burden u too much robert

Comment: i have learned a lot from SO answers, also it needs a lot of practice time to be better

Comment: http://imgur.com/2wWQ0d0 robert last question, why got some blank html there.?   should i get rid of it?

Comment: i think it's css related because the html doesn't have blank html

Comment: i think `height: 1200px;` is the cause

Comment: robert if i remove code from html  <div class="news"> until </div> it will work?

Comment: will the script running?

Comment: Never mind i already figure it out. haha It's working i remove <div class="ano"> until the </div> and then the result it doesnt show the blank html

Comment: if you needed anything contact me or just write a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can access the properties via the `index` on the `data` property as so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'news.json',
    data: {
        get_param: 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(
                data[index].Id,
                data[index].Pair,
                data[index].PubDate,
                data[index].Provider,
                data[index].Market
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Which produces

```
8ca2df56-2523-4bc3-a648-61ec4debcaaf  /Date(1463775846000)/ null 
74b2d7c7-bc2c-40ee-8245-7c698befa54d  /Date(1463775247000)/ null 
0ee3cd96-1df8-49ba-b175-7a75d0840973  /Date(1463773687000)/ null
```

To handle the templating you can create a function that returns the markup for each item:

```
function template(title, provider, summary) {
    var $temp = $('<div/>');
    $temp.append($('<h3/>', {
        text: title
    }));
    $temp.append($('<h4/>', {
        text: provider,
        class: 'author'
    }));
    $temp.append($('<p/>', {
        text: summary
    }));
    console.log($temp);
    return $temp;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/enki-code/4ec2b6efa84dfed8922b390d2a1a4c5a/raw/dc94405f12d1d5105e54584a6c53ca30d1863b4a/so.json',
    data: {
        get_param: 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('.content-news').append(template(data[index].Id, data[index].PubDate, data[index].Provider));
            console.log(
                data[index].Id,
                data[index].Pair,
                data[index].PubDate,
                data[index].Provider,
                data[index].Market
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Here is an [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/enkicode/6n3paus2/3/) of your fiddle as an example.

You'll likely have to make a few small adjustments to the CSS and whatnot to get it looking how you like.

Comment: FYI `data[index]` is same as `element` or `this`

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Try insert with this link url http://subscriptions.fxstreet.com/json/news.aspx?c=A0DC975D13C44CE697EC&i=englishnewscharts

Comment: Works for me? What's the problem.

Comment: Try `url: 'https://subscriptions.fxstreet.com/json/news.aspx?c=A0DC975D13C44CE697EC&i=englishnewscharts',` instead. Works for me.  Note the **HTTPS**.    [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enkicode/gy875o4x/1/)

Comment: ohh https.. okay the data already capture last problem is the layout u can see robert solution.  but when i tried using his solution it doesnt show any any data by using http or https.

https://jsfiddle.net/robert11094/65zjvy5k/3/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `$.parseJSON` or `$.getJSON`. It will be easier to find problems.
Reference: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: `$.parseJSON` has no relevance here. The data passed to success handler is already parsed